# Json files to own domain

Tags: php, json

Don't know if this is the right place but, i'm using an API, Fortnite to be more precise, and the json files has the images url, for example `www.apiwebsite.com/fortniteimage1.png`. Is possible to pass that image to my own url automatically, like `media.myurl.com/fortniteimage1.png` ?

Comment: If you want to host it under your domain you must download them first. 
 `file_get_content` and `file_put_contents` will help you with this.

Comment: I think this is it, but download is the .json file or all the images?

Comment: You need to download images only. So process images url with something like `file_get_contents('www.apiwebsite.com/fortniteimage1.png')` and then save it to some folder on your server.

Comment: Wow, nice i got it! But the json file has 8 images, can i use something like $response['image'] to get all?   (json looks something like this https://hasteb.in/pubesefo.json )

Comment: No , you can't fetch them all at once.

Answer (score -2):

You need to download the images to your local server. I recommend using curl for that, just look at the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/book.curl.php), there is a lot of examples there.

After downloading them, they must be in a directory that is served publicly, if you are using some framework, usually is the "public" directory, where other assets (JS, CSS, images) are also located.

That way, the images will be in your domain and will be served from there, like:

https://my-crazy-domain.net/images/fortnite/person-avatar.jpg

I think that if the question was more closely related to "How can I do this in PHP" would be more fit.

Anyway, I hope you achieve what you need.